# Error when updating 8.7.12 to 8.8.5

Tags: security

When I update my  8.7.12 site to 8.8.5 I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Installer\InstallerKernel::installationAttempted() in /usr/www/users/XXX/core/includes/errors.inc:311 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/users/XXX/core/includes/errors.inc(125): _drupal_get_error_level() #1 /usr/www/users/XXX/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(638): error_displayable() #2 /usr/www/users/XXX/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(622): _drupal_exception_handler_additional(Object(Error), Object(Error)) #3 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler(Object(Error)) #4 {main} thrown in /usr/www/users/XXX/core/includes/errors.inc on line 311

Can anyone advise? I am uploading the files via FTP.

Comment: Please update the original question with the new information, rather than asking it again. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,I did that, but I just got told the question was closed.

Comment: You didn't update the question; you answered to a comment with a comment, which isn't updating the question. For that, you need to click on the _edit_ link given right under the question itself.